# cmake "exporting" shared library on windows

Tags: cmake

I'm writing a small library.
I'd like to build it as shared library and generate "MyLibraryConfig.cmake" file which then can be used by my other projects to find my library.

The only problem I have is to figure out the name/path to file which is used for linking under Windows - there are two files being generated: mylibrary.dll and mylibrary.dll.a.

So I'd like to generate MyLibraryConfig.cmake file with something like:

"set(MYLIBRARY_LIBRARIES /blah/blah/mylibrary.dll.a)"

so then MYLIBRARY_LIBRARIES can be used with target_link_libraries for my other projects.

How can I get name for this linkable file? I'd be nice if the solution was platform independed (returning .so wile on Linux and .dll.a on Windows)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're planning on making your library available to your other projects *without installing it* then you want the CMake command [`export`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3aexport).  For example:

```
export(TARGETS MyLib FILE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/MyLibraryConfig.cmake)
```

This creates the file MyLibraryConfig.cmake in the same directory as your top-level CMakeLists.txt, and can just be [`include`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3ainclude)d in other CMake projects.

---

If you're planning on *installing* your library, then you want to make use of [`install(EXPORT ...)`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3ainstall) instead:

```
install(TARGETS MyLib EXPORT MyLibraryConfig
            RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
            LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
            ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib/static)
install(EXPORT MyLibraryConfig DESTINATION cmake)
```

This will install the file MyLibraryConfig.cmake to `<install path>/cmake`, and can then be `include`d by other projects.

Comment: thank you for your answer. It looks interesting and useful, however I look for solution *with* installing ;)

Comment: Typical! :-)  I've added further details on how to handle the install case.